# How to display a dynamic html table generated in an external script in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

In  Admin/Dashboard/pages  myPage/edit

```
[insert_php] include('path/to/external/script.php'); [/insert_php]
```

Inside script.php, I build a html table: $tbl.
How can I echo the $tbl on myPage?

Note: In the end of the script if I test the content of $tbl by typing die(var_dump($tbl))), I get the correct html string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom page template (see http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-custom-page-in-wordpress how it works) and then add your PHP snippet to this template.